# glob.iglob to find all .txt files in all sub-directories yields error

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

Simple code gives the below error. It's directly from the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

`TypeError: iglob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'`

```
import glob
for filename in glob.iglob('C:\\**\\*txt', recursive=True):
    print filename
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you're using Python 2.7 and reading the Python 3.5 documentation.

Answer (score 7):

The `recursive` parameter has been added in python 3.5, which means version `3.4.3` also has that problem.

If you don't want to upgrade your python version, you can use [glob2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glob2), which supports recursive calls (`**`) by default.